# jquery function doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

My resizeAreas function doesn't trigger in `$(document).ready` function. Here's the [link](http://licenta-dragosniculescu.rhcloud.com/clientSide/interfaces/2.Test/tasks.html) to the app. I have also tried `$(document).load` but same result.

This problem is not consistent. But most of the time the page doesn't load correctly. If the list of task have the same height and 4 equal(as height) lists on the row then they are loaded correctly else they're not. To make sure that you see how it must look you can move a task element from one list to another. I don't have the reputation to post images.

Here is most of the javascript code:

```
function makeDropArea() {
  var widthArea = $(".taskListing").width() / 2 - 55;
  var heightArea = $(".taskListing").height(); 

  $('.dropArea').width(widthArea);
  $('.dropArea').css('margin-left', 5 + 'px');
  $('.generalInfo').css('margin-left', 5 + 'px');
  $('.generalInfo').css('width', widthArea * 2 + 220 - 45);
  $('.subTaskHeader').css('width', widthArea + 25);
}

function makeDropElement(){
  var widthEl = $('.dropArea').width() + 25 ;
  $('.task').width(widthEl);
}

function taskListingSize(){

  var width = getWidth();
  var height = getHeight() * 80 / 100;
  $('.taskListing').css('width', width);
}


function resizeAreas() {
   $('.taskListing').each(function(){  

     var highestBox = 0;
     $('.dropArea', this).each(function(){

       if($(this).height() > highestBox) 
         highestBox = $(this).height(); 
     });  

     $('.dropArea',this).css('min-height', highestBox);  
   });    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  menu();
  taskListingSize();
  makeDropArea();
  makeDropElement();
  resizeAreas();  //<-- this is the one with the problems

  $(".dropArea").resize(resizeAreas());

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    taskListingSize();
    makeDropArea();
    makeDropElement();
  });
});
```

Thanks.

**Update 1:**

I've done some more testing and this bug is only on chrome and firefox but not on IE. The problem appears only on the openshift platform.

Comment: resizeAreas() is called in the wrong area. remove the `()` and it may work

Comment: I tried it. Same output. Any other ideas?

Comment: try renaming the function, maybe it's a reserved name

Answer (score 1):

Either change:

```
$(".dropArea").resize(resizeAreas());
```

To:

```
$(".dropArea").resize("resizeAreas");
```

Or:

```
$(".dropArea").resize(function(){
  resizeAreas();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review but the proplem persists. I think that the line of code that is causing it, is the line of code above the one that you suggested me to change. When i use debug it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
 $(".dropArea").resize(resizeAreas);
```

Or

```
 $(".dropArea").resize(function(){
       resizeAreas();
  });
```